# Selenium Exception Error: Element id=fname not found

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit4

In this particlular selenium recorded code When I am running it in eclipse using JUnit It is showing me error Element id= fname not found

package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class msFsitRegistration extends SeleneseTestCase {

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    setUp("http://192.168.1.146/fsit-mis/index.php?route=common/login", "*chrome");
}
public void testMsFsitRegistration() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("/fsit-mis/index.php?route=common/login");
    selenium.type("name=username", "admin");
    selenium.type("name=password", "admin");
    selenium.click("css=span.button_middle");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.useXpathLibrary("xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Employee Registration')])[2]");
    selenium.open("fsit-mis/index.php?route=employee/emp_registration");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.type("id=fname", "Shiraz");
    selenium.type("id=lname", "A Ansari");
    selenium.type("id=ecode", "FSIT-125");
    selenium.type("id=uname", "shiraz");
    selenium.type("id=password", "shiraz");
    selenium.type("id=confirm", "shiraz");
    selenium.type("id=email", "shijju@gmail.com");
    selenium.select("id=status", "label=ACTIVE");
    selenium.select("id=usrGroup", "label=Fortune Soft");
    selenium.click("xpath=(//input[@name='gender'])[2]");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.type("id=mobile", "8088762599");
    selenium.click("id=doj");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.click("link=1");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.click("id=dob");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.click("link=31");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.select("id=designation", "label=Test Engineer");
    selenium.click("css=option[value=\"265\"]");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.select("id=department", "label=Software Testing");
    selenium.click("id=insert");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.type("id=mobile", "8088762598");
    selenium.click("id=insert");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    assertEquals("Password Contain Atleast 5 element", selenium.getAlert());
    selenium.click("id=password");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.type("id=password", "shiraz");
    selenium.type("id=confirm", "shiraz");
    selenium.click("id=insert");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
}
```

}

please help me as soon as possible..

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the `Thread.sleep(5000);` commands. Insert `selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.isElementPresent('element_locator')", "5000");` instead, e.g. `selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.isElementPresent('id=fname')", "5000");`